# Saving a PNG to a Redis Server

Tags: image, redis

I'm trying to save a png generated by Canvas2Image to a Redis server and then display it again as an image.
I can't think of any way to do this and by searching Google I can't find any solution. Does anybody know how to do this?

This is for a website I'm making where anybody can draw on a canvas in real time.

Answer (score 2):

Redis has a binary safe protocol, and most standard instructions are fine with arbitrary binary data as both keys as values. There is no need to base-64 (or otherwise) encode, as long as your library supports the binary-safe aspect. For example, with `StackExchange.Redis` (for .NET) you can pass a `byte[]` as the value to `StringSet`, and the result of `StringGet` can be cast to a `byte[]`.

Then the only question becomes: how to get the binary of the png; but that should just be standard IO.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to encode a PNG as a base64 byte encoded string. Redis can then store the string like any other string.

If you'd like users to be able to draw in real time on the same image, it might be more effective to maintain the image as an SVG and share the image via client to client web sockets.

Comment: please provide a link to documentation or examples

Comment: redis is binary-safe throughout for ... ages; there is no need to base-64 encode anything; the only question is: does the specific client library support binary data?